# build.gradle.kts Java Functions

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I am trying to to call java functions in my build.gradle.kts

```
val time = java.time.LocalDateTime.now()
```

But it tells me that 'time' is an unsolved reference.

Other java imports do not work either.

What do I have to change to be able to use these imports?

Comment: which version of gradle / IntelliJ (assuming you're using IntelliJ)

Did you try to run gradle in command line? (./gradlew build). I don't see any reason why your code is not working as it is.

Comment: Strange behavior, it works for me in REPL, so should theoretically work on kts https://imgur.com/a/z8q5WTc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.LocalDateTime
```

```
val time = LocalDateTime.now()
```

Taking these apart fixed everything.